# Add Property page value to sharepoint ASP page

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2013

I have a simple SharePoint 2013 webpart that will simply use the marquee tag to scroll text across the part. I have one personalization part in the configuration section: the text to scroll. The question is, How do I get the property value from there into my asp part? I can;t seem to get anything to work inside there and nothing shows up in Intellisense. here's the C# code for the property:

```
protected string text;
[Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared), WebBrowsable(true),
WebDisplayName("Text To Display"),
WebDescription("The Text you want to scroll across the screen")]
public string ScrollingText
{
    get
    {
        return text;
    }
    set
    {
        text = value;
    }
}
```

And here's the asp text with the last attempt I made:

```
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left"><%this.ScrollingText;%></marquee>
```

Aside from this not being available in intellisense, i get a "only assignment,call,increment,decrement,await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement. error on ScrollingText.ascx.g.cs

Comment: You must post your entire code. What type of WebPart ? Visual Web Part ? You must modify the xml in accord to see the property

Comment: This is pretty much the entire code. Its a visual webpart that I simply added an html tag to and then added a property. I have no xml file. don't have a clue about needing one or how to update it

Comment: If is a visual web part you have two code file, one where place the property and another with aspx and aspx.cs. See [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/188019/Creating-Visual-Web-Part-Properties) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19490046/custom-visual-web-part-properties-sharepoint) in Elements.xml you declare also the default value for Property.

Comment: Thanks for the links, but I already have the code foe a property (see example) and the first link didn't really describe how i can get my property into the actual part.